# When querying pg_class for index names in postgres, why do some of them appear prefixed with a #?

Tags: postgresql

When querying pg_class for index names (e.g.: `SELECT relname FROM pg_class;`), some but not all of the index names come back prefixed with a # sign. What does this mean?

```
                         relname                           
-----------------------------------------------------------
some_table_name_one                                     
#some_index_name_one_idx                       
some_index_name_two_idx              
some_index_name_three_idx                    
#some_index_name_four_idx                   
#some_index_name_five_idx                   
some_table_name_two
```

Comment: Because you (or someone in your team) created them.

Comment: Are you saying that this has no special meaning and that those indexes were created with those names? I don't think anyone did this. We have used pg_repack on the tables in the database - could it be a side effect of that?